# collapse tree view css table at initial

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to collapse tree view but unable to do that please help me you can view below added the code snippet. i want tree view to be collapse each node initially as per retirement it should expand particular node.

for example when i run this code this should display **item1** and **item5**. when i click on **item1** it should be display **item2** and **item4** not **item3**. now you can understand what is my issue.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function () {
        //Gets all <tr>'s  of greater depth
        //below element in the table
        var findChildren = function (tr) {
            var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));
        };

        var el = $(this);
        var tr = el.closest('tr'); //Get <tr> parent of toggle button
        var children = findChildren(tr);

        //Remove already collapsed nodes from children so that we don't
        //make them visible. 
        //(Confused? Remove this code and close Item 2, close Item 1 
        //then open Item 1 again, then you will understand)
        var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
        subnodes.each(function () {
            var subnode = $(this);
            var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
            children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
        });

        //Change icon and hide/show children
        if (tr.hasClass('collapse')) {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        } else {
            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();
        }
        return children;
    });
});
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.level1 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.level2 td:first-child {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.collapse .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/collapse.gif");
}
.expand .toggle {
    background: url("http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/images/expand.gif");
}
.toggle {
    height: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2">
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse collapsable level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 5</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse collapsable level1">
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to update your html and set it into default mode which you want.
please replace your html with this.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr data-depth="0" class="expand level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" style="display: none;">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2" style="display: none;">
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" style="display: none;">
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="0" class="expand collapsable level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 5</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse collapsable level1" style="display: none;">
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Negi Rox